# preventing side-effects in R expression

Tags: r, metaprogramming, side-effects

I'd like to create a function `prevent_side_effects(expr, envir)` that executes `expr` in environment `envir` but has read-only access to the variables and functions in `envir` and all parent environments.

Is locking `envir` and locking all the symbols therein the only way to do this, or is there a better way?  If I go the locking route is it necessary to walk up the graph of parent environments and lock those as well?

Here is a reproducible example that demonstrates how this function would behave:

```
grandparent.env <- environment()
parent.env <- new.env(parent=grandparent.env)
env <- new.env(parent=parent.env)

env$x <- 1
parent.env$y <- 2
grandparent.env$z <- 3

grandparent.env$f <- function() cat('function defined in grandparent env\n')

out <- prevent_side_effects(envir=env, expr={
    cat(sprintf('%i %i %i\n', x, y, z))
    #> 1 2 3

    f()
    #> function defined in grandparent env

    # The following all throw errors or just define new local variables such 
    # that variables in env, parent.env, and grandparent.env are masked but
    # unchanged.
    x <<- 1000
    y <<- 1000 
    z <<- 1000

    x <- 4
    y <- 5
    z <- 6
    cat(sprintf('%i %i %i\n', x, y, z))
    #> 4 5 6

})

cat(sprintf('%i %i %i\n', x, y, z))
#> 1 2 3
```

Comment: If would be nice if you included a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that we could run to test any possible solutions.